# How to insert Bitwise value MongoDB database?

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb, postgresql

**How to insert bitwise datatype in mongodb? I gave an example from PostgreSQL,I want do same concept in mongodb:**

```
CREATE TABLE test (a BIT(3), b BIT VARYING(5));
INSERT INTO test VALUES (B'101', B'00');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (B'10', B'101');
ERROR:  bit string length 2 does not match type bit(3)
INSERT INTO test VALUES (B'10'::bit(3), B'101');
SELECT * FROM test;
  a  |  b
-----+-----
 101 | 00
 100 | 101
```